# Boost multi-index based orderbook

Tags: c++, boost, container

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278204/stdunordered-map-how-to-track-max-min-key-at-any-time), I'm using Boost multi-index to implement orderbook. So far my code looks like this:

`"CommonsNative.h"` contains `typedef int64_t myDecimal;` and `enum Side { Buy, Sell };`

```
#pragma once

#include "CommonsNative.h"
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>

using boost::multi_index_container;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct OrderBookItem {
    myDecimal price;
    int32_t lots;
    OrderBookItem(myDecimal price_) :price(price_), lots(0) {

    }
};

typedef multi_index_container
    <OrderBookItem, indexed_by<

    hashed_unique<
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem,myDecimal,price)
    >,

    ordered_unique<
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem,myDecimal,price),
    std::greater<myDecimal> /* sorted beginning with most frequent */
    >

    >> OrderBookContainer;

class OrderBook
{
public:
    OrderBook(void);
    ~OrderBook(void);
    void Add(Side side_, myDecimal price_, int lots_) 
    {
        if (side_ == Buy) {
            // inserts or returns existent
            OrderBookContainer::iterator it = buyContainer.insert(price_).first;
            // how to add lots i.e. OrderBookItem.lots += lots_?
            // auto curLevel = buyContainer.get<name>(price);
            // curLevel.lots += Lots;
        } else if (side_ == Sell) {
            // inserts or returns existent
            OrderBookContainer::iterator it = sellContainer.insert(price_).first;
        }
    }
private:
    OrderBookContainer buyContainer;
    OrderBookContainer sellContainer;
};
```

I have the following questions:

1. For here:

   > ```
   > OrderBookContainer::iterator it = buyContainer.insert(price_).first;
   > ```

   If I already have an item with `price = price_` I receive it in \$O(1)\$ (from hashtable). If such a level doesn't exist, then is it added in \$O(log n)\$? If I'm wrong, then what should I write to get an item if it exists (in \$O(1)\$) otherwise add it (in \$O(log n)\$)?
2. Once I have an item, how can I modify `lots` to something like this?

   ```
   OrderBookItem.lots += lots_
   ```

Comment: javapowered ..... time to change your nick? ;-)

Comment: not using java for 3+ years so probably can change to c#++powered :)

Comment: The second question is off-topic, as well as the second sub-question of the first question.  We cannot assist with adding new implementation, but we can review everything else.  I've already given some advice of my own below.

Answer (score 3):

- `myDecimal` is an absolutely unhelpful name overall.  I don't see any need to give `int64_t` a `typedef` here, but even if there is one, then it should still use a better name.
- Empty `void` parameters are not needed in C++:

  > ```
  > OrderBook(void);
  > ~OrderBook(void);
  > ```

  You also don't need these defaults as the compiler will provide them for you.  They would only be necessary if you need to overload them *and* will still need default versions.
- It's a little less-readable not having whitespace after commas:

  > ```
  > BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem,myDecimal,price)
  > ```

  Not only that, but you already add this whitespace in other places.  Keep it consistent.

  ```
  BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem, myDecimal, price)
  ```
- You use different styles of curly braces.  C++ doesn't restrict you to a particular one, so choose one you prefer and stick with it.
- Although this line has been commented out, are you still using C++11?

  > ```
  > // auto curLevel = buyContainer.get<name>(price);
  > ```

  If so, then you can replace `OrderBookContainer::iterator` with `auto`:

  ```
  auto it = buyContainer.insert(price_).first;
  ```

  ```
  auto it = sellContainer.insert(price_).first;
  ```